# Inserting modals through ajax call not working

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to display users data from another partial page through ajax call which contains modal for each users. Modal works fine normally, but when they are inserted through ajax, button doesn't even trigger them. I can't provide full code, but here is the sample

```
<button class="modal-btn" data-modal="view">VIEW</button>

<div id="view" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content col border-radius">
    <h4 class="p-x-6 p-y-5 m-2">View</h4>
  </div>
</div>


.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999999;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.modal-content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  left: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  z-index: 999999;
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(8%);
  }
  65% {
    transform: translateY(6%);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateY(4%);
  }
  95% {
    transform: translateY(2%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

(function iife() {
  "use strict";



    function closestEl(el, selector) {
        var doc = el.document ||
          el.ownerDocument;
        var matches = doc.querySelectorAll(selector);
        var i;
        while (el) {
          i = matches.length - 1;
          while (i >=
            0) {
            if (matches.item(i) === el) {
              return el;
            }
            i -= 1;
          }
          el = el.parentElement;
        }
        return el;
      }
      var modalBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-btn");
      modalBtns.forEach(function addBtnClickEvent(btn) {
        btn.onclick = function showModal() {
          var modal = btn.getAttribute("data-modal");
          document.getElementById(modal).style.display = "block";
        };
      });
      window.onclick = function closeOnClick(event) {
        if (event.target.className === "modal") {
          event.target.style.display = "none";
        }
      };
    }());
```

Is there any way to make it work when retrived from a partial page?

Answer (score 0):

First insert work fine ? Right ? that happen becasue when you append new modal via ajax. They has same `id="view"`. So javascript can't get elementById case there is more than 1 unique id... The solution is, at the time you append new modal, provide for them unique id..

```
<button class="modal-btn" data-modal="{UNIQUE_ID_}">VIEW</button>

<div id="{UNIQUE_ID_}" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content col border-radius">
  <h4 class="p-x-6 p-y-5 m-2">View</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The thing is both buttons and modal comes from another page with unique ids for each modal and button. I have the same setup in another page without ajax and it just works fine..